# How to completely deactivate the touchpad in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Is it possible / how to deactivate the touchpad so, that it even stays disabled, if no mouse is connected?

System: Dell Inspiron 6400, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Start.
2. Type device manager into the Search box. Click the device manager result, and the Device Manager window will pop up.
3. Expand Mice and other pointing devices.
4. Right-click the touchpad's entry. In the menu that pops up, click Disable.
5. Confirm your choice in the pop-up window.